# Ember, Ember-data and Rails relations error: "Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I connect Ember to a Rails API which delivers some JSON.

I'm trying to get relations working (`product hasMany images`) but it keeps giving me this error:

```
Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined
```

My Models:

```
App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
  images: DS.hasMany('image'),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
});


App.Image = DS.Model.extend({
  product: DS.belongsTo('product')
});
```

Rails renders json as:

```
{
  "products":[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "product title",
      "images":[
        {
          "id": 1,
          "urls":
          {
            "thumb":"http://domain.com/thumb/image.jpg",
            "original":"http://domain.com/original/image.jpg"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to "sideload" my images in Rails, so the JSON became:

```
{
  "products":[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "product title",
      "image_ids": [1]
    }
  ],
  "images":[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "urls":
      {
        "thumb":"http://domain.com/thumb/image.jpg",
        "original":"http://domain.com/original/image.jpg"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Rails' ProductSerializer:

```
class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  embed :ids, :include => true

  attributes :id, :title

  has_many :images

  methods :image_urls

end
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you were using embedded JSON in your example. You need to use the EmbeddedRecordsMixin https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/embedded_records_mixin.js and set the appropriate flag to mark `images` as being embededd

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've tried adding `{embedded: 'always'}` as second parameter for `hasMany`, but it didn't work. Could that be because I needed this Mixin? I now have Rails rendering JSON with sideloaded images, which works nice. See my answer below.

Comment: Yes, you would need to use the EmbeddedRecordsMixin for the `{embedded: 'always'}` to work

Comment: Thanks Igor, though your answer is correct (+1), I mark my own answer as accepted, because ember advises on sideloading relationships. http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/